# How to distribute records based on column

Tags: mysql, sql, distribution

I have a table storing competition entries. 
Contestants must enter text and can optionally upload a photo

When I display entries on a page I paginate through 9 at a time.

How can I ensure as much as possible that each page contains at least one entry with a photo in it (presuming there is enough photo entries for one per page)? It would probably be sufficient to distribute entries with photos evenly amongst the pages

Comment: You don't really care about the display order, just that photos are evenly distributed, right?

Comment: Correct - preferably in order of submission but not really important

Comment: Possibly converting the following example from Oracle SQL might point to a solution but I'm not sure if that's even possible in mysql - http://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/sql-–-row_number-analytical-function-mod-even-distribution/   (need to copy and paste link as SO not handling weird URL)

Comment: I have idea: just select that X=8 records without picture, and UNION with select that returns Y=1 record with pic. You can also make these X and Y numbers dynamic, and calculate them by some function that counts total picture and non-picture rows, to get better distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was one of the more challenging questions I've seen recently -- thanks for that!  I'm not able to get it working using a single SQL statement, but I was able to get it working (at least it appears) like this.  Basically it tries to determine how many results will be returned, then how many of those have photos, and uses a percentage of the photos divided by the number of pages (using CEILING to ensure at least one for the first few pages).

Anyhow, here goes:

```
SET @page = 1;
SET @resultsPerPage = 9;

SELECT @recCount:= COUNT(Id) as RecCount
FROM Entries;

SELECT @photoCount:= COUNT(Photo) as PhotoCount
FROM Entries
WHERE Photo IS NOT NULL;

SET @pageCount = CEILING(@recCount/@resultsPerPage);
SET @photosPerPage = CEILING(@photoCount/@pageCount);
SET @nonPhotosPerPage = @resultsPerPage - CEILING(@photosPerPage);

SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT *, 
        @rownum := @rownum + 1 row_number
      FROM Entries JOIN    (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
      WHERE Photo IS NOT NULL
   ) a 
WHERE a.row_number > (@photosPerPage*(@page-1))
   and a.row_number <= (@photosPerPage*(@page))
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT *, 
        @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 row_number
      FROM Entries JOIN    (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
      WHERE Photo IS NULL
   ) b
WHERE b.row_number > (@nonPhotosPerPage*(@page-1))
   and b.row_number <= (@nonPhotosPerPage*(@page))
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ddbc7/6).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you randomly order the rows:

```
order by rand()
```

This doesn't guarantee a photo on every page, but it helps.

The alternative is to do something like this:

```
select *, @seqnum:=@seqnum+1
from t
where nophoto
select *, @seqnum:=@seqnum+8
from t
where photo
```

Then sort by seqnum.  What makes this cumbersome is handling the cases where there is fewer than one photo per page and more than one photo.  The random method is probably sufficient.

Comment: I'm not sure that would help as there's no reason why it won;t be a random distribution anyway - it't not like the photo records are grouped

Answer (score 0):

For each page, do this (eg for page 3, page size 10):

```
select ...
from ...
where has_photo
order by created
limit 3, 1
union
select ...
from ...
where not has_photo
order by created
limit 27, 9
```

This query breaks up the two types of rows into two separate queries recombined by union.

Comment: I thought of that - however that only works if I know the proportion of photo to non-photo

Comment: So do a query to find that out first